# Why do Windows Updates which trigger reboots of live web servers at peak time?

Tags: windows, windows-update

Why do Windows Updates which trigger reboots of live web servers at peak time?

Is there any way I can stop this happening?

[image]

Windows Update is already configured to install updates at 6am, but the server rebooted at 09:45am.

[image]

Updates should be installed during the maintenance window from what I can see:

[image]

Comment: Yes, group policy

Comment: Can I use that on a server which isn't on a domain?

Comment: Yes.  It's called local group policy.

Comment: ... but on Windows Server 2012 R2, you don't need it, you can just configure Windows Update directly not to install updates automatically.  (But if you want them automatically, but at a time of your choosing, then you need local group policy.)

Comment: I *do* want them installed automatically, but just not at peak time!  The maintenance task window is set for 6am. So why did it reboot at 09:45?  See my updated post.

Comment: From what I can see - yes. See screenshot 2.

Comment: I've now posted the Windows Update settings screenshot..  If I click the highlighted link, it shows screenshot 2 which clearly says the maintenance time is 6am.

Comment: But the original screenshot implies the update will cause a server reboot within 15 minutes of installation - irrespective of *any* settings, and it was installed at 09:47.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83056/discussion-between-harry-johnston-and-nickg).